# Proper way to get 'infinite loading' progress bar with minimum duration delay using QProgressDialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

**Problem**

I am trying to use [`QProgressDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html) to display a modal dialog window that shows an 'infinite loading' progress bar, but which also takes advantage of the minimum duration which can be specified before showing the window. I am able to do it using a bit of hacky code, but wanted to ask if there is a more correct way to do it.

**Use case**

A query is made to some back-end service and the results may come quickly or may take a little more time. If the results are returned 'quickly', eg < 500ms, no dialog should show (to avoid a dialog box flickering on screen). If the results take 'more time', the modal dialog should appear (allowing the user to potentially cancel the operation, etc).

**Code**

Initialization

```
m_progress = new QProgressDialog(this);
m_progress->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
m_progress->setLabelText("Looking up data...");
m_progress->setMinimumDuration(500);
connect(m_progress, SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(onProgressCanceled()));
```

'Look up data' button onClicked slot (sends request to back-end and shows dialog)

```
// HACKY CODE ----------
//
m_progress->setMaximum(100);    // some value != 0 (0 is the value passed to setValue)
m_progress->setValue(0);        // starts the minimum duration timer
m_progress->setMaximum(0);      // set maximum to 0 to get 'infinite loading' progress bar
//
// HACKY CODE ----------
```

onProgressCanceled slot

```
m_progress->reset();
```

onResults method (callback that handles returned results)

```
m_progress->reset();
```

That is the entirety of the relevant code.

The reason for the hack is that in the Qt source, there is this explicit check:

```
(d->bar->value() == -1 && progress == d->bar->maximum())
```

If the maximum is set to 0 (for 'infinite loading') *before* the value is set to 0 (which starts the minimum duration timer), then `QProgressDialog::setValue` simply returns. The `d->bar->value` is initialized to -1 and reset to -1 when `QProgressDialog::reset` is called. It's almost as if this specific use case of `QProgressDialog` ('infinite loading' but with a minimum duration delay) is being singled out.

**Question**

Is there a way to achieve the same result but without the use of the hacky code that I'm missing? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Have you thought of using a timer each time the operation starts and cancel the timer when the operation finishes? The timer can trigger the display of the progress dialog.

Comment: I considered that, but it would essentially be duplicating the purpose of the `forceTimer` in `QProgressDialog`.

Comment: `QProgressDialog` is a convenience class. If it doesn't work for you, then you have every right to roll your own and just use it.

Comment: Sure but it seems odd that this one particular case (which I don't think is any sort of corner case or such) would need a workaround. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something 'obvious'.